# Dynamics facebook share buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this section in vbhtml :

```
<section class="white">
    @For Each item In Model
        @<div class="BNItem">
            <p class="title">@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Titre)</p>
            <p class="description">@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Description)</p>
            <!-- Your share button code -->
            <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://..." data-layout="button_count"></div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    Next
</section>
```

This creating as many `<div>` that there are item in the model.
For each item I want to share the content of the two `<p>` with the Facebook's script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.fb-share-button').live('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'HyperArts Blog',
                    link: 'http://...',
                    picture: 'http://...',
                    caption: 'title', //first <p> content
                    description: 'description', //second <p> content
                    message: ''
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

How can I achieve that ? Or which way do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many searchs (and tests) I've found an solution : 
So I've my differents Items and for each item I create a facebook button with a `share-button` class and two `data-` attribute, title and description

```
 @For Each item In Model
        @<div class="BNItem">
            <p class="title">@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Titre)</p>
            <p class="description">@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Description)</p>

            <div class="share_buttons">
                <div>
                    <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-xs btn-facebook share-button" data-title="@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Titre)" data-text="@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Description)">
                        <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Partagez !
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    Next
```

So in JQuery I catch these two `data-` and create my Facebook's feed :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".share-button").click(function () {
                var title = $(this).data("title");
                var description = $(this).data("text");
                FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: title,
                    link: 'http://...',
                    picture: 'http://...png',
                    caption: 'My Site',
                    description: description,
                    message: 'test'
                });
     });
});
```

Works perfectly. I Hope that help someone else !